# Is it possible to export sky texture with gltf exporter?

Tags: lighting, world, gltf

I’m using a sky texture node to light my scene for export to gltf, is it possible to export the sky texture light as part of the gltf?

Answer (score 1):

Not as part of the glTF model itself, no.  There have been a few proposals for IBL and environment storage in glTF (one recent proposal is in [PR #1956](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/pull/1956)), but none of these are ratified by Khronos or included with the Blender glTF exporter as of yet.

In general many applications find it more convenient to keep the model separate from the environment, for various reasons:

- Models can be interchanged among many environments.
- When multiple models appear in the same environment, users don't want the size cost of including the same environment in multiple files.
- Different applications use different means of storing environments (HDR, EXR, KTX2, and various forms of prefiltering and mipmapping with convolutions), so one storage mechanism may not fit all rendering engines.

So for these reasons, it seems best to keep the environment texture out of the glTF file.  Even so, several glTF viewers include the ability to load custom IBLs and environments from separate files.

---

**UPDATE**

Based on the comment below, we know the target rendering environment is ThreeJS, so I'll add a little extra detail here.  You can use Image-based Lighting (IBL) by loading an HDR file, with code like this:

```js
var envPath = 'path/to/whatever.hdr';

var pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( renderer );
pmremGenerator.compileEquirectangularShader();

new THREE.RGBELoader()
    .setDataType(THREE.UnsignedByteType)
    .load(envPath, (texture) => {
        envMap = pmremGenerator.fromEquirectangular(texture).texture;
        pmremGenerator.dispose();
        scene.environment = envMap;
        scene.background = envMap;
    });
```

(Above code based on [this sample](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/gltf-vscode/blob/fb3691ca08a2dc239e7822b110bcee0e158ecaab/pages/threeView.js#L93-L104), licensed Apache 2.0).

Using a full lighting environment like this can help make PBR details look a lot more realistic on a model, particularly one that features metallic surfaces and other PBR effects.  You can get high-quality HDR files to use from [PolyHaven](https://polyhaven.com/hdris) and other online sources.  Of course, you can preview and render with these same environments in Blender as well.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation emakey. The end goal for my current project is in a web page through threejs. I’ve tried using lights with shadows in three but the shadows are faceted so was hoping for an easier approach at the blender end. I’ve also tried baking the textures with lighting but this returns a very flat discoloured appearance. Without shadows everything looks as expected and I’m guessing I’ll just have to figure out how to work the dirlightshadows better in three. Thanks again and back to the drawing board I go 

Comment: I added some details on using Image-Based Lighting in ThreeJS.

Comment: Yes thanks, I have used the HDR loader in threejs but not sure I can cast shadows from there? When I add a directional light with dirlightshadows enabled the shadows are faceted and display as small triangles. I have also tried reducing the shadow camera frustrum to improve quality but this is very tricky and returning little joy. I feel this is an area I need to work in to enable an accurate lighting environment and eventually would like to be able the hours of the day in specific locations

Comment: In general I don't think IBLs cast shadows in most real-time systems, but you can try asking the ThreeJS experts on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I add a sphere around my whole environment, then set a HDR texture on the sphere, also I add emission to the texture, it works like HDRI and you can export your whole environment in glb file.